# Referring composite component ID in f:ajax render

Tags: jsf, composite-component, clientid, ajax-update

I am writing a composite component that is intended to wrap an input element, and augment it with an 'optional field' designation and h:message element below it. 
Here is the component (in input.xhtml file):

```
<composite:interface/>
<composite:implementation>
  <div>
  #{component.children[1].setStyleClass(component.children[1].valid ? '' : 'inputError')}
    <composite:insertChildren/>
  </div>
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="optional" 
      rendered="#{!component.parent.children[1].required}" 
      layout="block" >
    #{msgs['common.optional.field']}
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:message id="msgId" 
       for="#{component.parent.children[1].id}" errorClass="error"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

Again, the intended usage of the component is to wrap an h:input* element which is expected to be the first and immediate child of it in a using page.

In a using page I would then write:

```
    <h:form id="f1">
    <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="2" style="width: 80%">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <col width="40%" />
            <col width="60%" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="sectionBody" for="i1"
            value="Input 1"></h:outputLabel>
            <my:input id="ii1">
            <h:inputText id="i1" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="0"
            required="true" label="Input 1">
            </h:inputText>
            </my:input>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="sectionBody" for="i2"
            value="Input 2"></h:outputLabel>
            <my:input id="ii2">
            <h:inputText id="i2" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="0"
                label="Input 2">
            </h:inputText>
            </my:input>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <br />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" tabindex="1">
        <f:ajax listener="#{terminalImportBean.addTerminal}" 
          execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This would work just fine using normal posts. 
However if I add add f:ajax validation for "Input 1" (id="i1") and try to re-render the composite (ii1) using the following:

```
...   
         <h:outputLabel styleClass="sectionBody" for="i1"
            value="Input 1"></h:outputLabel>
         <my:input id="ii1">
            <h:inputText id="i1" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="0"
            required="true" label="Input 1">
               <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.checkInput1}" 
                  event="blur" 
                  render="ii1"/>
            </h:inputText>
         </my:input>
...
```

I gen an error in the browser during ajax response processing:

```
malformedXML: During update: f1:ii1 not found
```

I tried using `f1:ii1`, `:f1:ii1`, but to no avail. When I use `msgId` or `:f1:ii1:msgId` it works. Does anybody know why?

I am using Mojarra 2.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the composite component does by *itself* not render anything to the HTML. Only its children are been rendered to HTML. There does not exist any HTML element with ID `f1:i11` in the generated HTML output. Open the page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Look in there yourself. There's no such element with that ID. JavaScript/Ajax is encountering exactly the same problem. It can't find the element in order to update it.

To solve this, you'd need to wrap the entire composite body in a HTML `<div>` or `<span>` and assign it an ID of `#{cc.clientId}` which basically prints [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId--).

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        ...
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Then you can reference it as below:

```
<my:input id="foo" />
...
<f:ajax ... render="foo" />
```

You can even reference a specific composite component child.

```
<f:ajax ... render="foo:inputId" />
```

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/jsf-update-with-ajax-non-jsf-things)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)